# Выравнивание формы по центру на css

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, такая проблема, сделал форму входа. По горизонтали по центру выровнял с помощью `margin: 0 auto;`. Но по вертикали не выровнять, как сделать по центру (вертикали)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top: calc(50% - высота_блока/2);
left: calc(50% - ширина_блока/2);
```

Answer (score 5):

как вариант

```css
.modal{
  padding: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, может кому понадобится, добавил:

`position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -...;
 margin-left: -...;`

Вместо точек размер блока / на 2.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите у родителя

```
display: flex; // FlexBox
align-items: center; // выравнивает по вертикали 
justify-content: center; //выравнивает по горизонтали
```